# Neologismo para 'drinkability' (inglês)

Tags: estrangeirismos, neologismos

Há algum termo em português que já venha sendo usado ou proposto, que consiga representar o significado de 'drinkability' do inglês?

Mas, não no sentido de potabilidade como existente em alguns dicionários, mas sim no sentido do caráter/qualidade do que é bebível e que está associado a experiência, prazer, satisfação. Algo como "bebilidade", "bebabilidade", ou "bebebilidade' ?

**EDIT - Exemplos de uso:**

- No calor de 45C do Rio de Janeiro, a **bebabilidade** de um copo de água gelada é maior que a de um copo de água quente.
- Este vinho é muito adstringente, acho que isto o torna áspero e reduz sua **bebabilidade**.
- No verão cervejas menos alcoólicas possuem uma **bebabilidade** maior que as mais alcoólicas, segundo um estudo.

(Usei bebabilidade nos exemplos por ser mais [eufônica](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/euf%C3%B4nica))

Comment: _"já venda"_ o _"já vem"?_ were you thinking in spanish, using "venga", and just got confused?

Comment: @robertotomás Eu interpretei *que já venda* como *que já seja usado, aceite*, mas és capaz de ter razão. Só que não é preciso ir ao espanhol, basta o português *venha*.

Comment: Era erro de digitação. Corrigido.

Comment: Hoje mesmo bebi uma cerveja que anunciava em seu rótulo _de boa drinkability_. Acho que essa é (mais) uma palavra que vai permanecer em inglês. No meio cervejeiro, até hoje só ouvi a versão em inglês mesmo.

Comment: **bebibilidade** parece ser o correto, principalmente quando você pensa em **bebível** mas esse termo soa muito estranho então EMHO eu usaria a palavra **qualidade**. simples, prático e transmite a idéia que você quer: Qualificar a bebida como Boa ou de Alta Qualidade.

Comment: A evitabilidade dessas impronunciabilidades é de fácil evidenciabilidade. Já ouvi até monstruosidades como "miserabilidade" (o que há de errado com "miséria"?!)

Comment: Parece que fui a única em dar definições oneológicos. Eu pensava que as refêrencias eram aglo importante por aqui....

Answer (score 4):

Em um comercial de cerveja brasileiro já ouvi o termo bebabilidade.

> Como [este](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-palavra-bebabilidade/29964) artigo sugere, seguindo a conjugação do verbo beber seria:  **bebibilidade**, mas podemos facilmente tropeçar na pronúncia da palavra  bebibilidade então as pessoas do marketing do comercial de cerveja  utilizaram o termo bebabilidade para ser mais conveniente de pronunciar.

Até o próprio termo de *drinkability* que está sendo questionado pode ser um neologismo em inglês, usado atualmente nas propagandas de cerveja internacionais e em livros de degustação de bebidas alcoólicas. Tente fazer uma pesquisa no ngrams do Google em inglês verá que não é uma palavra muito comum.

Isto seria como a palavra *feedback*, não recordo de ouvir alguém dizer retroalimentação. Geralmente para alguém que não entenda pode tentar simplesmente: retorno e se a pessoa entender usaria *feedback*.

Comment: [A palavra bebabilidade](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-palavra-bebabilidade/29964)

Answer (score 2):

Eu e os meus amigos costumamos usar [bebível](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/beb%C3%ADvel). Não no sentido de potável, mas no sentido de ser uma bebida que se bebe bem ou não.

> -Como é essa bebida? É bebível?
>
> -Não, não se pode beber.

ou

> -Como é essa cerveja novo? É bebível?
>
> -É uma categoria do caraças.

Comment: Mas e quanto à qualidade ou o caráter do que é bebível ? Ex: Volátil x Volatilidade; Sustentável x Sustentabilidade. Acessível x Acessibilidade.

Comment: @Luciano [A palavra bebabilidade](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-palavra-bebabilidade/29964)

Answer (score 1):

Para *drinkable*, diria "bom de beber".  Para *drinkability*, talvez "gosto"/"sabor"/"aroma"?  Certamente nunca ouvi nenhuma palavra no sentido de uma tradução literal de *drinkable*, e tais palavras como "bebabilidade", "bebibilidade" ou "bebilidade" me remetem mais a "bêbado" que a "beber".

Comment: Para drinkable já ouvi bastante a versão bebível, aliás formal nos dicionários. Parece bem natural. Soa bem. Mas sua substantivação (drinkability), é a questão.

Answer (score 1):

Por que não bebibilidade? Vem de bebível e tomaria forma com "b" no substantivo, da mesma forma que amável, visível e provável.

Comment: Desculpem! Esse "que" com circunflexo foi erro da digitação automática...rs

Comment: Corrigido. Podes tu mesmo editar tuas contribuições, se for necessário.

Answer (score 1):

Drinkability é só para vinhos ou cervejas (não para água).

Explicada aqui em inglês: [Drinkability is hard to precisely define. It is a slightly 'blurry" term, open to interpretation. Wine professionals often categorize wine as being high or low on the drinkability scale.
Drinkability is a measure (largely subjective of course) as to how agreeable or easy a wine is to drink.](https://www.thekitchn.com/wine-word-drinkability-173561)

"Vinho doce com intensa riqueza deste distinto varietal é sentida nas frutas exóticas, também gengibre e jasmim, o seu paladar é untuoso, mas com acidez vivaz, que eleva o conjunto e traz muita bebilidade."
500ml [bebilidade](https://www.winebrasil.com.br/luigi-bosca-gewurztraminer-granos-nobres) [neologismo que não é muito bonito]

Em francês, se diz que um vinho é: agréable à boire

Em português também: [agradável (de beber)](http://www.adegadovinho.com.br/artigo.php?recordID=61&n=Gloss%C3%A1rio%20do%20vinho)

> AGRADÁVEL– expressão usada quando o conjunto aroma-sabor está
>   organolepticamente equilibrado.

Na verdade, drinkability seria realmente: agradabilidade

> Revela leveza e agradabilidade ao paladar, com fim de boca aveludado.
>   Harmoniza perfeitamente com polenta e massas com molhos, frango assado
>   na brasa, queijos e embutidos. Também pode acompanhar chocolates meio
>   amargos. Melhor apreciado de 13 a14°C. Graduação Alcoólica 10%.
>   Conteúdo 750ml. Vinho Nacional. [agradabilidade-português Brasil](https://www.imigrantesbebidas.com.br/vinho-vino-di-bartolo-tinto-suave-750ml)
>
> FERNÃO PÓ - VINHO DE MESA ROSÉ Vinho com aromas a fruta fresca
>   vermelha e biscoito. De cor rosada-avermelhada, perfumado na boca. A
>   ligeireza e agradabilidade são os seus pontos fortes. Acidez média.
>   Perfeito como aperitivo, com sardinha assada.
>   [agradabilidade-português-Portugal](http://www.fernaopo.pt/vinhos.php)

Answer (score 0):

[potabilidade](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/potabilidade)
Qualidade do que é potável.

[Potable](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20potable) is a word in english too.

Comment: Roberto, a pergunta pede um equivalente a *drinkable* no sentido de *agradável* [(sentido 2 do Oxford)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/drinkable?q=drinkable) e não de *potável*.

Comment: thats true but doesn't apply. but i didn't give an answer based on a synonym for "pleasant". I gave an answer based on a synonym for "potable" which is the same as "drinkable" in english. the above definition is from priberam. and here is priberam's definition for potável: _Que se pode beber._

Comment: "Potabilidade" isn't what I asked for. It doesn't cover the other meanings of drinkabillity.

Comment: ok, fair enough. but it does literally mean the same thing as drinkability.

Comment: @robertotomás: Yes. It also means potability. But "also". Not exclusively it. The question was pointed on the other meaning, as commented by Jacinto with the link (at the second definition): http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/drinkable?q=drinkable

Comment: ooh, fair enough again. I was not aware that the second was a literal meaning of the word. I thought that was borne out of advertising, just like he suggested in the question, and wasn't literally a part of the word.

Comment: potable and potability is for water only. If water is potable,it is drinkable: it will not make you sick (ill). It has nothing to do with pleasure, as in drinkable wine,